# Allowed file extensions for video and photo php upload

Tags: php, security, upload

I want to give users the ability to upload photos and videos via mobile with my PHP script. What are the only extensions I should *allow*? I do not want to limit Android or Windows phone users from uploading.

Right now I'm excluding several, but I fear that this allows for slippage:

```
$blockedExtensions = {'php','exe','bat'}
```

Comment: Did you also check for the mime type server side, right?....so if someone have a malicious php script(f.i a shell) and change the extension to png instead of php and upload the file, it rejects the file, right?

Comment: No, I did not. Do you know of a good sample script?

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on file extensions. Images can be checked with exif_imagetype() or GD functions, which return false if the file is not an image.